# Como colocar uma cor na tr de um Radio Selecionado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp

É possível a cor da linha mudar após o usuário selecionar um radio da lista levando em conta que estou fazendo o submit da pagina ? o problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer pois como pode ver abaixo minha Table  puxa os dados do banco dinamicamente

> listarAgenda

essa e a Table

```
    <table width="199" border="1" class="table table-condensed" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
                  <thead class="style4">
                    <tr bgcolor="${cortop}" >
                      <th width="21" align="left" >&nbsp;</th>
                      <th width="178" align="left" ><strong>EXAMES / PROCEDIMENTOS</strong></th>
                    </tr>
                <c:forEach var="item" items="${listarAgenda}">                                  
                    <tr bgcolor="#F4F4F4">
                      <th align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio4" value="radio4" onclick="JavaScript:selecionarAgenda(${item.idAgenda},'${item.agenda}',${item.idLocalAtend},'${item.local}', 0, '');" /></th>
                      <th align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="#" onclick="JavaScript:selecionarAgenda(${item.idAgenda},'${item.agenda}',${item.idLocalAtend},'${item.local}', 0, '');">${item.agenda}</a></th>
                    </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                  </thead>
                </table>
```

JavaScript:selecionarAgenda

```
function selecionarAgenda(idAgenda, nomeAgenda, idlocal, local, idmedico, medico){
                document.forms[0].sc.value=document.getElementById("div1").scrollTop-2;
                diaSemana();
                if(idAgenda > 0){
                document.formConsulta.selectMedico.value=0;
                document.formConsulta.medico.value='';
                document.formConsulta.idagenda.value=idAgenda;
                document.formConsulta.nomeagenda.value=nomeAgenda;
                document.formConsulta.selectLocal.value=idlocal;
                document.formConsulta.local.value=local;
                document.formConsulta.idtipoconsulta.value=4;
                document.formConsulta.idmedico.value=0;
                document.formConsulta.action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controlador?acao=agendaunica';
                document.formConsulta.submit();
                }else{
                    document.formConsulta.nomeagenda.value='';
                    document.formConsulta.idagenda.value=0;
                    document.formConsulta.idtipoconsulta.value=0;
                    document.formConsulta.idmedico.value=idmedico;
                    document.formConsulta.medico.value=medico;
                    MM_jumpMenu();
                }
            }
```

A minha `Jsp` se comunica com a `servlet` controlador?acao=agendaunica fazendo assim o submit da pagina após selecionar o `radio`. Teria como mudar a cor do radio selecionado após o submit porque o usuário reclama que não lembra em qual Agenda está.

Answer (score 1):

Olha o que você você pode fazer é o seguinte. Pelo que vi, você possui **${item.idAgenda}**, atribua o id para sua row e grave no seu método de seleção.

```
document.formConsulta.agendaSelecionada.value= idAgenda;
```

Então no seu java, grave este parâmetro, para que no retorno você possa saber a agenda selecionada e adicionar uma classe CSS para colorir o fundo. Você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  document.getElementById("id").className = "corFundo";
});
```

Uma outra alternativa seria fazer via GET. No submit do seu formulário salve o parâmetro da agenda selecionada e recupere o mesmo da url:

Ex: www.meusite.com.br/agendas?as=12

Comment: fiz da primeira maneira, deu certo, mas está pegando a cor somente na primeira linha. S eu selecionar outra linha por exemplo a cor do fundo só vai pra primeira.  document.formConsulta.LinhaTabela.value= idAgenda;     e criei o método document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
                document.getElementById("LinhaTabela").className = "corFundo";
              });

Comment: document.getElementById("LinhaTabela") . O id aqui deve ser o id da sua agenda que voce vinculou na sua TR, pelo parametro ${item.idAgenda}.

Comment: sim, está  pegando esse parametro e atribui no   document.formConsulta.idagenda.value=idAgenda; conforme meu javascript ali em cima. ai eu atribui a   Row da tabela  <tr id="idagenda" > e fiz o metodo que voce postou, e não está mudando a cor

Comment: Tente debugar e verificar se está vindo o parâmetro esperado no id da sua row em que você está adicionando a classe: document.getElementById("id") deve ser igual ao parametro <%=selecao%> então desta forma ele só irá pegar o elemento selecionado. Você pode executar via console para testes.